# Azure AD B2C adding suffix in custom provider Azure AD login page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Since there is no way to login via own domain insted of "@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" I have a question about automaticly adding suffix to login via custom provider which is Azure AD which has synchronized accounts using Azure AD Connect. I'd like my users to login using only their username and automaticly adding "@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" before they click "Login". Is it someway possible?

Workflow:

1. User goes to Sign In in my application
2. Sign In redirects to Azure login page
3. User selects Domain login button and is redirect to custom provider page
4. User types his username and "@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" is either automaticly typed on eg. onBlur event or something like that or "@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" is permanently non erasable from input and something can only by typed before "@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is expected when you use login_hint or domain_hint parameter in the URL. Please find the reference document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin?pivots=b2c-user-flow

In case if you are not using the above mentioned parameter, please share the URL mentioned in screenshot to investigate more.e.g. (https://login.microsoftonline.com/f65d9497-.../)